# How to cascade -> operator?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

I have the following:

```
typedef struct Node_struct
{
    int number;
    Node *nextNode;
    Node *prevNode;
} Node;
```

and later

```
Node *nodeInSet = lookup(set, number);
nodeInSet->nextNode = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
nodeInSet->nextNode->prevNode
```

the last line is saying: "expression must have pointer-to-class type". I can't see how my code is wrong. Since `nodeInSet->nextNode` is a `Node *`, I think I should be allowed to write `nodeInSet->nextNode->prevNode`. What is not working here?

Comment: I also suspect that you are using the wrong compiler otherwise [Do not cast the return value from `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495). You are allowed to write that, but you really shouldn't. From the sample code it's not possible to say why is the error happening, can you post a reproducible sample? Also, wouldn't `nodeInSet->nextNode->prevNode` be `nodeInSet`? if the list is correctly populated.

Comment: inside `Node_struct` the `typedef Node` is not yet defined, so you should declare `struct Node_struct *nextNode`

Comment: a struct definition should not be typedef'd.  typedef'ing clutters the code, leads to mis-understandings, adds no value, and clutters the compiler name space.   Rather always use: 'struct Node_struct'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `prevNode` and `nextNode` members have incomplete type, you have to write it like this

```
typedef struct Node_struct
{
    int number;
    struct Node_struct *nextNode;
    struct Node_struct *prevNode;
} Node;
```

or

```
typedef struct Node_struct Node;
struct Node_struct
{
    int number;
    Node *nextNode;
    Node *prevNode;
};
```

The reason is that you can declare a poniter to an incomplete type, but if you try to dereference the pointer, like when you use the `->` operator, then the type must be known, because the size of the type is needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can change your code to this.

```
typedef struct Node_struct
{
    int number;
    struct Node_struct *nextNode;
    struct Node_struct *prevNode;
} Node;
```

Comment: It's not optional, _you can change ..._ sounds as if it were.